# SSRS Shared DataSet with Parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS Project that will have 5 reports (*.rdl files).  All reports will output the same data, the only difference being "ClientName" in the WHERE Clause.

So I created a Shared Dataset in my project.  Inside that shared dataset, I added a parameter @ClientName.

In my report (*.rdl file), I added a dataset that referenced my shared dataset.  How do I make this dataset sent a hard coded value for "Client Name" to the shared dataset so it doesn't prompt the user to enter one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to your rdl as well, turn the parameter visibility off and set the default value to the static client name (ie default="Fred").  When the SSRS report runs, it should pass the local parameter with the default value to the shared dataset without the end user having to select or enter a value.

Comment: That is what I did.  In the *.rdl dataset, I added a parameter named "@ClientName" and set the Parameter Value to the client's name.  It still prompts me for the Client Name.  But I can't find how to set the parameter visibility.

Comment: OH WAIT.  I was looking in the wrong parameters location.  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard code the value, you can add it as the **Parameter Value** in the Dataset's Parameter tab.

[image]

Comment: I did add a parameter value in the dataset's parameter tab.  Not on the shared dataset, but in the local dataset on the *rdl file that references the shared dataset in the project.

Comment: OH WAIT. I was looking in the wrong parameters location. Thank you for the help